# How do I specify the python interpreter for YARN to use?

Tags: python, anaconda, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to run a standalone python script on yarn that uses anaconda to calculate the mean shift (using the code from [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_mean_shift.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-mean-shift-py)). I can run this code locally, however when I submit the application to YARN with the launch command `python MeanShift.py` I get an error from YARN stating:

```
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:753)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

Looking into the YARN application logs I can see that this is because of the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MeanShift.py", line 4, in <module>
    from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift, estimate_bandwidth
ImportError: No module named sklearn.cluster
```

I have added Anaconda to the PATH for all of the nodes in my YARN cluster. Is there a configuration that I am missing to tell YARN which python interpreter to use? Do I need to use a different command to start the script?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try: `/path/to/anaconda/bin/python MeanShift.py`

Comment: @NehalJWani I tried that, but it didn't work so I tried /path/to/anaconda/bin/python27 and that does work. If you submit an answer I will accept it.